# Jquery clone() on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a problem with cloning multiple elements using Jquery clone().

I have HTML:

```
<div id="is_watermark">
    <input class="is_watermark" type="checkbox" name="is_watermark" value="1" checked />
    <span>Add watermark</span></div>
<div id="minify_image">
    <p>By default image is 400px. You can change size:</p>
    <input class="minify-radio" type="radio" name="minify" value="200"  /><span>200px</span>
    <input class="minify-radio" type="radio" name="minify" value="400" checked="checked"/><span>400px</span>
    <input class="minify-radio" type="radio" name="minify" value="600" /><span>600px</span>
    <input class="minify-radio" type="radio" name="minify" value="800"/><span>800px</span>
</div>
```

Then I use ajaxFileUpload which basically creates new form and sends image through ajax:

I have in my Javascripts the following:

```
var oldInputElements = $('.minify-radio, .is_watermark');
var newInputElements = $(oldInputElements).clone(true);
console.log(oldInputElements);
console.log(newInputElements);
```

In Firebug I see that `oldInputElements` is fine and represents what I had in HTML, but the newly created `newInputElements` contains all elements but with only one general value coming from radio elements. For example, if at the moment the radio was chosen with value 600, then in the newly created variable `newInputElements` all five input elements (including checkbox!) would have value 600.

Is it a bug, or I simply missing something?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle which shows the problem. It does sound like a bug though.

Comment: When cloning elements only the default values are cloned along with it, any selections on dropdown lists or radio buttons will not be cloned along with it. Try to see if `clone(true, true)` works but if not you will have to store any selected values along-side in a separate object and re-select/populate the cloned elements after insertion.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you do `oldInputElements.clone(true)`?

Comment: oldInputElements.clone(true) - does the same on my side, producing error.

Comment: >Could you provide a fiddle    I was just trying to create it in Fiddle and it looks that there it works fine.

Comment: @Volder I also thought it is fine but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:radio").change( function() {
   $("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
   $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

You can use this code. Removing checked property/attribute and then adding the attribute to current selected item/node.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXKwy/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've used the sample code from you - and it works fine. Here is a screen for this from Firebug: http://i.imgur.com/fum3lyR.jpg Also I couldn't represent it in Fiddle (as I mentioned in comments above). But when I use my initial (seems that environment makes sense) I get this: http://i.imgur.com/AIDLfwF.jpg  And the very strange thing is it shows proper values on the line for the object, but when I expand it - all the values are 600, and 600 is sent to the server.

Comment: Woah man, yeah huge difference. You checked in chrome's console with your actual code rather than which i gave you?

Comment: @ Aspiring Aqib In Chrome the behaviour is the same. For your sample code (onChange event it works fine), but for my initial code it is the same, for the newly created elements - the value is the same for all and comes from selected radio button.

Comment: ok, I didn't understand it was a joke, but thought you asked to check in Chrome additionaly to FF.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24377/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-volder)